# Move to new view after contact is select from CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I'm writing a concept chat app. I'm now at the point where a new chat could be started.

What I want is that when the user selects a contact using the `CNContactPickerViewController`, the picker is dismissed (this is working) and the contact details are send to a new chat view (this is not working). The error I get is that at `func contactPicker` the `delegate` returns `nil`. I have been following [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-contacts-framework/) tutorial in getting contact data from the Chat**s**ViewController to the ChatViewController. The relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

class ChatsViewController: UITableViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {
    var chats:[Chat] = chatData
    var selectedContact: CNContact = CNContact()
    @IBAction func createNewChat(sender: AnyObject) {
        let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return chats.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatCell
        
        let chat = chats[indexPath.row] as Chat
        cell.chat = chat
        return cell
    }
    
    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
        self.selectedContact = contact
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idContactSelected", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "idContactSelected" {
            let chatVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ChatViewController
            chatVC.contact = self.selectedContact
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the new chat ViewController.

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
    var contact: CNContact = CNContact()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.testLabel.text = contact.givenName
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

So in recap: I have a ViewController, I can press a button there to start a new chat, which opens the contact picker. Once a contact is selected, the `func contactPicker` is executed, but the contact data is never sent, nor the new chat ViewController is presented and the `delegate` is `nil`. Why is this happening? I assume it is because `delegate` is never set, only created, but in the tutorial this is all they do and it seems to work.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this.

**EDIT:** Solution in the end: I didn't need the delegate, I can just push data through `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier`. Also, the segue was not connected properly, reconnecting the segue fixed the transition not working.

Comment: Show your story board screen.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Nirav, here: http://imgur.com/ZiOzndu

Comment: From storyboard `ChatViewController` is your first screen. Right?

Comment: `ChatsViewController` is the first screen. The right-most screen is `ChatViewController`. Full overview storyboard: http://imgur.com/wKbcZDg

Comment: Then why are you performing segue in `ChatViewController`.

Comment: I was figuring that out just now. But where do I set the delegate then? I'm having troubles wrapping my mind around how to use this delegate to send data to the next viewcontroller, and how to make that viewcontroller appear.

Comment: Add whole code of your `ChatsViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this. Change your code something like this

`ChatsViewController`

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

class ChatsViewController: UITableViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {
    var chats:[Chat] = chatData
    var selectedContact: CNContact = CNContact()
    @IBAction func createNewChat(sender: AnyObject) {
        let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return chats.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatCell

        let chat = chats[indexPath.row] as Chat
        cell.chat = chat
        return cell
    }

    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
         self.selectedContact = contact
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idContactSelected", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         if segue.identifier == "idContactSelected" {
             let chatVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ChatViewController
             chatVC.contact = self.selectedContact
         }
    }
}
```

After that change your `ChatViewController`

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
     var contact: CNContact = CNContact()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         self.testLabel.text = contact.givenName
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks so much! It doesn't crash anymore (Because the delegate is out ofcourse), however it is not presenting the `ChatViewController`. I get no errors.. EDIT: I read that `performSegueWithIdentifier` needs to be called from the main UI thread, so I encapsulated it within `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. That is not working because the view is not in the window hierarchy then.

Comment: Using my answer you will get selected contact also in `ChatViewController`.

Comment: I understand, thank you. But the new viewcontroller is not presenting itself (The empty, new chat view controller that says "Success!" is never showing)

Comment: That's why i am saying try my code it will push your `ChatViewController` with the name of selected contact that you want.

Comment: I know. And I did. I literally copied your code into my project and it is not presenting the `ChatViewController`

Comment: Can you edit your question with the new code. So that i can understand the problem. Because i have created the demo of this and it will working correct in my side. So please edit your question with the new code of your.

Comment: I created a video of what is not happening: https://vid.me/w1SS The code is exactly the same as what you wrote. I copied all of yours, deleted all of mine, and you see this running in the video.

Comment: Have you added this `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idContactSelected", sender: self)` line in method `contactPicker ` of `ChatsViewController`

Comment: Please instead of showing me video please update your question with new code. So that i check what is the mistake. Also i have check the video of your project.

Comment: Have you change anything in storyboard? Because in code every this looks correct.

Comment: No, everything is still the same. I made a segue from the `ChatsViewController` to the `ChatViewController` as shown in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vKOMS.png Maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: Your `Segue identifier` is `mySegue`?

Comment: No, mine is still "idContactSelected", image just served as example how I hooked the segue up.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your whole code inside `ChatsViewController`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. Is there a way I can privately send you the project? Maybe that can clear things up..

Comment: Try to put the break point in `prepareForSegue ` method of `ChatsViewController` and check it is executing or not?

Comment: Is it going inside `IF block`?

Comment: Try to remove that segue from storyboard and create again?

Comment: Yes, it reaches `chatVC.contact = self.selectedContact`. So the segue exists.

Comment: I think that was it! Recreating the segue somehow fixed it. I now get to a screen where my contact name is displayed. Thank you Nirav!